# Using Github, CakePHP 3 and Composer

Tags: git, cakephp, github, gitignore

I am trying to find the best way to work with CakePHP 3 on GitHub with multiple workstations.

Scenario: I have installed CakePHP 3 with Composer into a fresh directory and created a git repository from it with the github cli. Using the default .gitignore delivered with cakephp. After pushing the repo to the remote server I started to work on that project.

Later at home I wanted to continue the work and ran into the following problem:
Both, Composer and GitHub (CLI and GUI) need a empty folder to install the cakephp core or clone the repo. So, what would be the best way to deal with that problem without deleting the .gitignore and push the whole cakephp core to the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If composer globally installed in your home computer, after clone just use below command in your project folder.

```
composer update
```

This command need only 1st time. Then cakephp core will download automatically.Then it will work fine.I think it's an easy solution.

Complex solution is,you can change git ignore file, then create repo, after clone in your home computer change again git ignore file.

Comment: Please excuse my late anwser, I have been on vacation. Your simple solution is working like a charm. I only had to copy the config/app.php by myself. Thanks alot!

Comment: but `compose update` will upgrade your packages too? Why not `composer install` from the project folder? both of these solutions create the cake app but are missing the bin/ folder with the cake shell, but the `update` command also alters the `composer.lock` file

Answer (score 0):

When you pull from github on another machine:

1. Install composer globally: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`
2. Clone your repo from github e.g. `git clone git@github.com:myuser/cakephpapp.git cakeapp`
3. Go into your repo e.g. `cd cakeapp` and then run `composer install`

Your `bin` folder will be missing unless it was committed to your repository. You can get another copy by creating a new cakephp app and then copying it:

1. Create new cakephp app: `composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app tempapp`
2. Copy the `bin` directory: `mv tempapp/bin/ ./bin`
3. Remove the new app: `rm -rf tempapp/`

If you've accidentally upgraded your packages or altered your `composer.lock` file (and have no code changes) you can reset the repo without removing `bin/` (this should be in your `.gitignore`)

1. `git reset --hard HEAD`
2. `git pull origin master`